# Befor the Auth::check() , Where and How can I set the users access to some functionality or pages

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5.8

Actually I am beginner in Laravel. By the way, I am using auth and there is a wonderful method, I mean  "check" of Auth facade that enable you to protect all routes or controller in that way you want. But Befor this I should say which users can use this route or controller and which users can't. 
I seach for it but I didnt find. 
Actually I miss a part of this authentication mechanism in Laravel.Please help me about this.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has a feature called Middlewares where you can check for the user role based on your role_id.
Please see the below link for more clear reference.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware

Happy Coding.:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use middleware for this kind of functionality. Read about middleware in laravel documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware)

Moreover you can use [this](https://github.com/santigarcor/laratrust) package to create role for users if you don't want to create roles from scratch. Just add user to a role and use the role name as the middleware.

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone through with ACL stuff in laravel??
Well it will work as per permission which is given by user as per it's role.
For an example Admin has all role so he can access anything. Employee has few rights to access modules so that will define as per need in laravel and that user that do not have access to use some module they'll get some error desgined by developer.

So this all handle through [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware), and generally that defines by `acl`

Anything else you want to know?